# Delphi Alt key + accelerator key plays a "wrong entry" sound

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm coding a custom buttonn derived from tExCustomControl wich, in turn, is derived from tCustomControl. The tExCustomControl component, takes care of painting and has an internal tLabel for caption display (my option for the tLabel was to facilitate the underlying of the accelerator char). In the tExCustomControl, I handle the "keyUp" event like this:

```
      if Char (Key) = AcceleratorChar then
          if AltKeyIsDown then
              if Assigned (OnClick) then
                 OnClick (Self);
```

This works fine, except for one thing: while holding down the Alt key and after pressing and realeasing the accelerator key, I get a "wrong entry" sound.

Why is this sound played? How can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks odd. Sounds like you gave the label an accel key but no focus control. Key up is wrong. Actions happen on key down. Don't use a label. Paint the text yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Alt key is pressed down while another key is pressed, the system generates a `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` which is then translated to a `WM_SYSCHAR` by the `TranslateMessage` function. The 'beep' is caused by the default processing of this message, which is typically used only for system menu accelerators.

You can prevent further handling of the message to prevent the beep. While you're there, you can process the key too.

```
procedure tMyExCustomControl.WMSysChar(var Message: TWMSysChar);
begin
  if Message.CharCode = Ord(AcceleratorChar) then
    OnClick(Self)
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Setting Key to 0 doesn't prevent further processing of the key?

Comment: The message is ignored. The WMSysChar is not executed.

Comment: @user - The message is never received? If your control does not have focus, no amount of processing on your control will prevent the beep. It's the active control then what beeps.

Comment: @Serac. This really odd! If you're right about the focus thing, ho

Comment: This is really wierd! If you're wright about the focus thing, how is that the OnKeyUp event of the tExCustomControl is triggered? It shouldn't be if, as you claim, the control has not focus.

Comment: @user - I don't claim that the control does not have focus. It was just one possible reason that you wouldn't receive wm_syschar, but then you're probably right that keydown wouldn't be called either. In any case, alt+key generates a wm_syschar, I would be interested in a case where it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the tLabel that acts as a caption. It receives the message but, since there was no focus control setted, Windows sounds the ding. Setting the focus control to the tExButton solves the problem. In fact, the ding was played at form level, hence, before the KeyUp event in the tExCustomControl. That's the reason why the tExCustomControl had no messages to process, they where already processed by the form.

Comment: That's what I told you in my comment. What you need to do is remove the label. It's the wrong way to implement a text caption in a custom control.

Comment: @David. If you read carefully the answer, youll see that I succeeded to avoid the ding, hence, the label was not the issue. At first, I was drawing the caption but I found very tricky to draw the accel key underlined. So I use the label wich does it automatically for me. I didn't also found any function or procedure that gives me a text with the accel key underlined. I'll appreciate If you show me an easy way to do this,

Comment: It's really easy to draw the accel key underline. Look at the source for TLabel. The win api does the work.

Comment: Also, I did read your answer. My comment said "Sounds like you gave the label an accel key but no focus control." Which is what your answer says. That's fine.

Comment: @David. I look earliest at the source for tLabel & found "DoDrawThemeTextEx", "DoDrawNormalText" and "DoDrawText". I'm not sure wich is the one I need. The first one is for themes, I presume. The third one is very tricky and the second is the one that uses the WinAPI. Is that one that I should use?

Comment: What are you doing with regards themes? Are you using themed api?

Comment: @David. OK. I used the WinAPI to display the caption (as you suggested) and it works fine. The issue is how I make Windows understand that when pressing Alt + accel char, is the tExButton that must handle the event? Or, in other words, how I tell Windows to associate the Alt + accel char with the tExButton? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really want to answer in comments more questions that are now becoming quite distinct from the original question. Especially as you have already answered your own question. I suggest that you ask a new question, or see if it has already been asked.